# Can I get outer document fields from nested top hits aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making use of the functionality that was added in Elasticsearch 1.5 to allow a top hits aggregation inside a nested aggregation. The problem I have is that once I have my top nested documents I want to be able to also get fields from their outer documents.

my pseudo aggregation structure is

```
nested: {
  some_other_aggreagation: {
      "top_hits": {
       }
  }
}
```

The top nested hits include the index, type and id of the outer document, so I could perform a secondary search, but I'd like to avoid that. My other option is to return all of the hits from the query (currently I only return the results of the aggregations) and then match up the documents with the events in my code, but that seems bad from a performance point of view.

Can anyone suggest something better? Thanks.